# Named argument `allowPrereleaseVersions' cannot be used for a parameter which has positional argument specified

Tags: c#, mono, nuget, xbuild

Trying to build NuGet on mono and getting:

```
error CS1744: Named argument `allowPrereleaseVersions' cannot be used for a parameter which has positional argument specified
```

running:

```
xbuild Build/Build.proj /p:Configuration="Mono Release" /t:GoMono || die
```

question: What is it? Is it bug or am I doing something wrong?

some analyse...

code :

```
    public void InstallPackage(string packageId, SemanticVersion version)
    {
        InstallPackage(packageId, version, ignoreDependencies: false, allowPrereleaseVersions: false);
    }
```

error comes from: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/mcs/ecore.cs#L5324

full log:

> XBuild Engine Version 3.2.0.0 Mono, Version 3.2.0.0 Copyright (C)
>   Marek Sieradzki 2005-2008, Novell 2008-2011.
>
> Build started 07/29/2013 09:24:01.
>   ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___** Project "/var/tmp/portage/dev-dotnet/nuget-2013.07/work/Build/Build.proj"
>   (GoMono target(s)):
>           Target RestorePackages:
>                   Project "/var/tmp/portage/dev-dotnet/nuget-2013.07/work/src/CommandLine/CommandLine.csproj"
>   (Build target(s)):
>                           Target PrepareForBuild:
>                                   Configuration: Mono Release Platform: AnyCPU
>                                   Created directory "bin/Release/"
>                                   Created directory "obj/Mono Release/"
>                           Target ResolveProjectReferences:
>                                   Project "/var/tmp/portage/dev-dotnet/nuget-2013.07/work/src/Core/Core.csproj"
>   (default target(s)):
>                                           Target PrepareForBuild:
>                                                   Configuration: Mono Release Platform: AnyCPU
>                                                   Created directory "bin/Release/"
>                                                   Created directory "obj/Mono Release/"
>                                           Target CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
>                                                   Copying file from '/var/tmp/portage/dev-dotnet/nuget-2013.07/work/lib/Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll'
>   to
>   '/var/tmp/portage/dev-dotnet/nuget-2013.07/work/src/Core/bin/Release/Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll'
>                                           Target CopyNonResxEmbeddedResources:
>                                                   Copying file from '/var/tmp/portage/dev-dotnet/nuget-2013.07/work/src/Core/Authoring/nuspec.xsd'
>   to '/var/tmp/portage/dev-dotnet/nuget-2013.07/work/src/Core/obj/Mono
>   Release/NuGet.Authoring.nuspec.xsd'
>                                           Target GenerateResources:
>                                                   Tool /usr/bin/resgen2 execution started with arguments: /useSourcePath /compile
>   "../../Common/CommonResources.resx,obj/Mono
>   Release/NuGet.CommonResources.resources" 
>                                                   Tool /usr/bin/resgen2 execution started with arguments: /useSourcePath /compile
>   "Resources/AnalysisResources.resx,obj/Mono
>   Release/NuGet.Resources.AnalysisResources.resources" 
>                                                   Tool /usr/bin/resgen2 execution started with arguments: /useSourcePath /compile
>   "Resources/NuGetResources.resx,obj/Mono
>   Release/NuGet.Resources.NuGetResources.resources" 
>                                           Target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies:
>                                           No input files were specified for target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies, skipping.
>                                           Target CoreCompile:
>                                                   Tool /usr/bin/dmcs execution started with arguments: /noconfig /debug:pdbonly /optimize+
>   /out:"obj/Mono Release/NuGet.Core.dll" /resource:"obj/Mono
>   Release/NuGet.CommonResources.resources" /resource:"obj/Mono
>   Release/NuGet.Resources.AnalysisResources.resources"
>   /resource:"obj/Mono Release/NuGet.Resources.NuGetResources.resources"
>   /resource:"obj/Mono Release/NuGet.Authoring.nuspec.xsd"
>   ../../Common/CommonResources.cs ../../Common/CommonAssemblyInfo.cs
>   ../../Common/GlobalSuppressions.cs Analysis/IPackageRule.cs
>   Analysis/PackageIssue.cs Analysis/DefaultPackageRuleSet.cs
>   Analysis/PackageIssueLevel.cs
>   Analysis/Rules/InitScriptNotUnderToolsRule.cs
>   Analysis/Rules/InvalidFrameworkFolderRule.cs
>   Analysis/Rules/MisplacedAssemblyRule.cs
>   Analysis/Rules/MisplacedScriptFileRule.cs
>   Analysis/Rules/MisplacedTransformFileRule.cs
>   Analysis/Rules/MissingSummaryRule.cs
>   Analysis/Rules/WinRTNameIsObsoleteRule.cs
>   Authoring/AssemblyMetadata.cs Authoring/AssemblyMetadataExtractor.cs
>   Authoring/EmptyFrameworkFolderFile.cs Authoring/IPackageBuilder.cs
>   Authoring/IPropertyProvider.cs Authoring/ManifestDependencySet.cs
>   Authoring/ManifestFrameworkAssembly.cs Authoring/ManifestDependency.cs
>   Authoring/ManifestFile.cs Authoring/ManifestMetadata.cs
>   Authoring/ManifestReader.cs Authoring/ManifestReference.cs
>   Authoring/ManifestReferenceSet.cs Authoring/ManifestSchemaUtility.cs
>   Authoring/ManifestVersionAttribute.cs
>   Authoring/ManifestVersionUtility.cs Authoring/NullPropertyProvider.cs
>   Authoring/PackageDependencySet.cs Authoring/PackageReferenceSet.cs
>   Authoring/PhysicalPackageAssemblyReference.cs
>   Configuration/ConfigurationDefaults.cs
>   Configuration/SettingsCredentialProvider.cs Configuration/ISettings.cs
>   Configuration/NullSettings.cs Configuration/Settings.cs
>   Configuration/SettingValue.cs EnvironmentVariableWrapper.cs
>   Extensions/CredentialProviderExtensions.cs
>   Extensions/EnumerableExtensions.cs Extensions/ObjectExtensions.cs
>   Extensions/PackageOperationExtensions.cs
>   Extensions/QueryableExtensions.cs Extensions/SettingsExtensions.cs
>   Extensions/TaskExtensions.cs Extensions/VersionExtensions.cs
>   FileModifiers/FileTransformExtensions.cs Http/CredentialStore.cs
>   Http/CredentialType.cs Http/ICredentialCache.cs
>   Http/IHttpWebResponse.cs Http/IProxyCache.cs
>   Http/MultipartWebRequest.cs Http/NullCredentialProvider.cs
>   Http/ProxyCache.cs Http/RepositoryOperationNames.cs
>   Http/RequestHelper.cs Http/STSAuthHelper.cs Http/WIFTypeProvider.cs
>   IEnvironmentVariableReader.cs IMachineWideSettings.cs
>   Logging/FileConflictResolution.cs Logging/IFileConflictResolver.cs
>   NETPortable/NetPortableProfile.cs
>   NETPortable/NetPortableProfileCollection.cs
>   NETPortable/NetPortableProfileTable.cs PackageRestoreConsent.cs
>   Packages/LocalPackage.cs Packages/OptimizedZipPackage.cs
>   Packages/UnzippedPackage.cs
>   PackageWalker/NuGetVersionNotSatisfiedException.cs
>   ProjectSystem/ProjectImportLocation.cs
>   Repositories/ILatestPackageLookup.cs ProjectSystem/IBatchProcessor.cs
>   Repositories/ICloneableRepository.cs
>   Repositories/ICultureAwareRepository.cs
>   Repositories/IPackageCacheRepository.cs
>   Repositories/IPackageReferenceRepository.cs
>   Repositories/IOperationAwareRepository.cs
>   Repositories/IServiceBasedRepository.cs Repositories/PackageName.cs
>   Repositories/UnzippedPackageRepository.cs
>   Resources/AnalysisResources.Designer.cs SemanticVersion.cs
>   SemanticVersionTypeConverter.cs Server/PackageServer.cs
>   GlobalSuppressions.cs IPackageManager.cs IProjectManager.cs
>   PackageSource/IPackageSourceProvider.cs
>   PackageSource/PackageSourceProvider.cs
>   PackageSource/PackageSourceProviderExtensions.cs
>   Packages/FrameworkAssemblyReference.cs
>   Packages/IFrameworkTargetable.cs Packages/IPackageMetadata.cs
>   Packages/IServerPackageMetadata.cs PackageWalker/ConflictResult.cs
>   Repositories/IDependencyResolver.cs PackageWalker/PackageSorter.cs
>   PackageWalker/IPackageOperationResolver.cs
>   PackageWalker/IDependentsResolver.cs PackageWalker/PackageAction.cs
>   PackageWalker/PackageOperation.cs PackageWalker/PackageTargets.cs
>   PackageWalker/PackageWalkInfo.cs ProjectSystem/NullFileSystem.cs
>   ProjectSystem/PhysicalFileSystem.cs
>   ConstraintProviders/AggregateConstraintProvider.cs
>   Repositories/AggregateQuery.cs Repositories/AggregateRepository.cs
>   ConstraintProviders/DefaultConstraintProvider.cs
>   ConstraintProviders/IPackageConstraintProvider.cs
>   Repositories/IPackageLookup.cs Repositories/MachineCache.cs
>   Repositories/NullConstraintProvider.cs
>   Repositories/PackageReference.cs Repositories/PackageReferenceFile.cs
>   Utility/CredentialResult.cs Utility/CredentialState.cs
>   Utility/CustomAttributeProviderExtensions.cs
>   Utility/DisposableAction.cs Utility/EncryptionUtility.cs
>   Utility/ExceptionUtility.cs Http/HttpUtility.cs
>   Http/ICredentialProvider.cs Http/IHttpClientEvents.cs
>   Repositories/LazyQueue.cs Repositories/ProgressEventArgs.cs
>   Repositories/SmartDataServiceQuery.cs
>   Repositories/BufferedEnumerable.cs
>   Repositories/DataServiceContextWrapper.cs
>   Repositories/DataServiceQueryWrapper.cs
>   Repositories/ExpressionRewriter.cs Repositories/IDataServiceContext.cs
>   Repositories/IDataServiceQuery.cs
>   Repositories/IPackageRepositoryFactory.cs
>   Repositories/ISharedPackageRepository.cs
>   Repositories/OrderingComparer.cs Extensions/AppDomainExtensions.cs
>   Extensions/AssemblyNameExtensions.cs
>   Repositories/SharedPackageRepository.cs Runtime/AssemblyBinding.cs
>   Runtime/BindingRedirectManager.cs Runtime/BindingRedirectResolver.cs
>   Runtime/IAssembly.cs Runtime/RemoteAssembly.cs
>   Extensions/CollectionExtensions.cs FileModifiers/Preprocessor.cs
>   FileModifiers/XmlTransfomer.cs Http/IHttpClient.cs
>   Utility/FrameworkNameEqualityComparer.cs Utility/IProgressProvider.cs
>   Utility/IVersionSpec.cs Utility/MemoryCache.cs
>   Utility/PackageComparer.cs Utility/PackageRepositoryHelper.cs
>   Utility/PackageIdValidator.cs Utility/PathValidator.cs
>   Http/RedirectedHttpClient.cs Utility/ProjectManagerExtensions.cs
>   Utility/ReadOnlyHashSet.cs Utility/VersionSpec.cs
>   Utility/WebRequestEventArgs.cs FileModifiers/XdtTransformer.cs
>   Logging/NullLogger.cs Logging/ILogger.cs PackageOperationEventArgs.cs
>   Logging/MessageLevel.cs PackageManager.cs
>   Authoring/PhysicalPackageFile.cs Authoring/PackageBuilder.cs
>   Authoring/PathResolver.cs Authoring/Manifest.cs
>   PackageSource/PackageSource.cs Packages/DataServicePackage.cs
>   Packages/DefaultPackagePathResolver.cs Packages/IPackage.cs
>   Packages/IPackagePathResolver.cs ProjectManager.cs
>   FileModifiers/IPackageFileTransformer.cs
>   Repositories/DataServicePackageRepository.cs
>   Utility/HashCodeCombiner.cs Http/HttpClient.cs
>   Utility/PackageDownloader.cs Utility/IHashProvider.cs
>   Utility/PackageEqualityComparer.cs PackageWalker/PackageMarker.cs
>   Packages/ZipPackage.cs Packages/IPackageAssemblyReference.cs
>   Packages/ZipPackageAssemblyReference.cs PackageWalker/PackageWalker.cs
>   PackageWalker/InstallWalker.cs PackageWalker/UpdateWalker.cs
>   PackageWalker/DependentsWalker.cs PackageWalker/UninstallWalker.cs
>   ProjectSystem/IFileSystem.cs
>   Repositories/PackageReferenceRepository.cs
>   Extensions/PackageExtensions.cs
>   Repositories/PackageRepositoryExtensions.cs
>   Extensions/FileSystemExtensions.cs
>   Repositories/PackageRepositoryFactory.cs
>   Resources/NuGetResources.Designer.cs
>   Extensions/ProjectSystemExtensions.cs Utility/PathUtility.cs
>   Utility/QueryableUtility.cs Utility/CryptoHashProvider.cs
>   Extensions/StreamExtensions.cs Extensions/StringExtensions.cs
>   Utility/PackageHelper.cs Utility/XmlUtility.cs
>   ProjectSystem/IProjectSystem.cs Repositories/PackageRepositoryBase.cs
>   Repositories/IPackageRepository.cs Packages/Constants.cs
>   Packages/IPackageFile.cs Packages/PackageDependency.cs
>   Repositories/LocalPackageRepository.cs Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
>   Utility/UriUtility.cs Utility/VersionUtility.cs
>   Extensions/XElementExtensions.cs Packages/ZipPackageFile.cs
>   /target:library /warnaserror+ /define:CODE_ANALYSIS /platform:AnyCPU
>   /reference:../../lib/Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll
>   /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.0/System.dll
>   /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.0/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll
>   /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.0/System.Data.Services.Client.dll
>   /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.0/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
>   /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.0/System.Security.dll
>   /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.0/System.ServiceModel.dll
>   /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.0/System.Xml.Linq.dll
>   /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.CSharp.dll
>   /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.0/System.Xml.dll
>   /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.0/WindowsBase.dll
>   /reference:/usr/lib/mono/4.0/System.Core.dll /warn:4
>   PackageManager.cs(97,75): error CS1744: Named argument
>   `allowPrereleaseVersions' cannot be used for a parameter which has
>   positional argument specified
>                                                   PackageManager.cs(100,29): (Location of the symbol related to previous
>   error) PackageManager.cs(97,48): error CS1744: Named argument`
>   ignoreDependencies' cannot be used for a parameter which has
>   positional argument specified
>                                                   PackageManager.cs(100,29): (Location of the symbol related to previous
>   error)
>                                           Task "Csc" execution -- FAILED
>                                           Done building target "CoreCompile" in project
>   "/var/tmp/portage/dev-dotnet/nuget-2013.07/work/src/Core/Core.csproj".--
>   FAILED
>                                   Done building project "/var/tmp/portage/dev-dotnet/nuget-2013.07/work/src/Core/Core.csproj".--
>   FAILED
>                           Task "MSBuild" execution -- FAILED
>                           Done building target "ResolveProjectReferences" in project
>   "/var/tmp/portage/dev-dotnet/nuget-2013.07/work/src/CommandLine/CommandLine.csproj".--
>   FAILED
>                   Done building project "/var/tmp/portage/dev-dotnet/nuget-2013.07/work/src/CommandLine/CommandLine.csproj".--
>   FAILED
>           Task "MsBuild" execution -- FAILED
>           Done building target "RestorePackages" in project "/var/tmp/portage/dev-dotnet/nuget-2013.07/work/Build/Build.proj".--
>   FAILED Done building project
>   "/var/tmp/portage/dev-dotnet/nuget-2013.07/work/Build/Build.proj".--
>   FAILED
>
> Build FAILED. Errors:
>
> /var/tmp/portage/dev-dotnet/nuget-2013.07/work/Build/Build.proj
>   (GoMono) -> (RestorePackages target) ->
>   /var/tmp/portage/dev-dotnet/nuget-2013.07/work/src/CommandLine/CommandLine.csproj
>   (Build) -> /usr/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets
>   (ResolveProjectReferences target) ->
>   /var/tmp/portage/dev-dotnet/nuget-2013.07/work/src/Core/Core.csproj
>   (default targets) -> /usr/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.CSharp.targets
>   (CoreCompile target) ->
>
> ```
>     PackageManager.cs(97,75): error CS1744: Named argument `allowPrereleaseVersions' cannot be used for a parameter which has
> ```
>
> positional argument specified
>           PackageManager.cs(97,48): error CS1744: Named argument `ignoreDependencies' cannot be used for a parameter which has
>   positional argument specified
>
> ```
>      0 Warning(s)
>      2 Error(s)
> ```

Comment: What is the signature of InstallPackage method? The one which takes 4 arguments.

Comment: @NikitaBrizhak it's hosted here: http://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Core/ProjectManager.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a bug in mcs compiler. You can use master version or wait for 3.2 update to get the issue resolved.

Comment: Thanks, I hope you will make fix release soon.